# Custom GraphQL Error types for Validation

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, graphql-js, express-graphql

Is this possible to set custom GraphQL Error types for at least `BAD_USER_INPUT` code?

On the backend I've got an error type something like this:

```js
throw {
    type: 'ValidationError',
    code: 422,
    success: false,
    message: `Something didn't work well`,
}
```

on Frontend I am still getting the same error type when some fields don't pass schema validation:

[image: Error from GraphQL]

That's not really comfortable to take care of the both error formats on the frontend.

Is it possible to somehow:

1. Except errors and BAD_USER_INPUT receive data response 200 and check it by success?
2. Or maybe it's just possible to make my format of error (the one I'm sending form backend)?

I already wanted to make it using `global error handler`:

```js
export default ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }, nuxtContext) => {
    console.log('Global error handler')
    console.log(graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward)
}
```

```js
apollo: {
...
// setup a global error handler (see below for example)
errorHandler: '~/plugins/graphql/apollo-error-handler.js',
...
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 0):

Formatting errors can be achieved in Apollo Graphql server using [formatError](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#for-client-responses) function. You can raise [custom errors](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#custom-errors) from your application from which the necessary error response can be constructed at formatError function.